# What strategy: Custom LINQ or SQL queries stored in database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

An app I'm working on uses Linq to EF extensively. It's multi-tenant so different customers store all their data all in the same database.

Some customers would like custom reports. Ideally, the definition for these custom reports would be stored in the database against the customer because it would be impractical to hard-code these reports into the main code (it would quickly get out of hand).

I've solved this in the past by storing SQL strings which are then evaluated using `context.SqlQuery(myReportSQL)`. It works well enough.

Two thoughts:

1. At the moment the SQL strings are not editable by the customer. It's managed internally to avoid the wrong sort of query being run. How would you suggest opening this up to the customer? A query builder interface (any suggestions for a plugin v welcome)? Something that allows only SELECT statements?
2. A better approach would be to use LINQ to EF queries because: it's easier to ensure it's a SELECT only, I can chain additional WHEREs on the end to ensure they only get the right data, and it's more readable.

So with option 2, how do you store this in a database and then effectively 'eval' it?

I have seen the Dynamic LINQ library which helps to a degree but I'm concerned it's getting old and might be dropped / not support EF6 etc.

Comment: Another thought occurs to me: storing the query in some kind of JSON format. Is there a standard I should follow?

Comment: On 1. if you open it up to the customer then who would you protect a customer from getting to another customers data?   On 2. how would a customer build up LINQ run time?

Comment: 1. Exactly - that is the problem with it! It would have to be parsed/checked very carefully. Not keen on this at all. One solution could be to let them query from a pre-defined query that contains only the data they're allowed to see.

Comment: And 2 - Well, I guess it's impossible. Hence my question here. Maybe I'm after a linq-style syntax that's parsed internally.

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this - but have you considered Entity-SQL?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used dynamic linq for a similar purpose, but had the same concern about not being built into the framework.  The idea was to store fragments rather than one large query.  For example if you want to show a column off a parent relationship you have "Parent.Column" as your expression for that column.  In this regard it's much simpler to author and maintain than SQL since you don't have write all the joins, etc.

We also had a concept of predicates, where you store an expression and an operator and are passed in a value.  For example, store "Parent.Column" and "Equals" and pass in values in a dictionary. e.g. dictionary["parentColumn"]

Since you mentioned this would be for reporting, have you considered using SSRS(SQL Server Reporting Services) which allows you to define datasources and let your business users create their own reports?  You may be able to handle your multi-tenancy by defining the datasources differently.

Comment: The other answers here are all useful but for me this is the best approach. It offers the security of the fragments that can be specified by the customer and then joined together in a safe way. And it leads naturally to a UI where you select fields and predicates and so on from drop downs or drag n drop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to store a query in any format, I would choose SQL, because that is the final form in which any db query will be executed, it's human readable, and it can be stored easily in a plain text format. That is of course exactly what databases do themselves with stored procedures and view definitions, therefore you may as well simply use the facilities provided by the database and work with stored procedure or view definitions.

Depending on the context your application is used in, an existing database reporting tool (eg. MS SSRS) will leverage database security and query features as well as providing a deployment platform.

To answer the question about how to open up the query to modification by users, you need to consider various questions:

- in what form would your users be most comfortable modifying queries (eg. SQL, graphic query builder, etc)
- what security restrictions you need to implement to ensure that users can only access appropriate DML commands, and authorised data (again, databases provide security features, so make sure you're not reinventing the wheel)
- what versioning facilities do you need to allow users to customise queries without affecting other users

Then decide your approach and design a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-tenant how to handle security with dynamic queries is that difficult part

I would start with Table-Valued Function where you hard code a parameter for the customer ID

Use it to build up some direct tables and also some common joins

[FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Views allow for security but unfortunately the don't let you pass a parameter (that I know of) so multiple customers could use the same view.   You could have a view that you make a version for each customer.